# Convert DB Items from english to spanish in android

Tags: android, locale

I would like to develop an android application with multi language support. If the user change the language how can I convert the data from DB into the corresponding language at runtime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create locale based strings.xml file.For that you need to create folder for the respective locale
    for example, when you want for german, create a folder by name 'res/values-de/' and keep the strings.xml
    file with translation in it.To test the application,To test it, we can set different locales via 
    Home > Menu > Settings > Locale & text > Select locale.

Hope this will help you.